# Diff of two variables in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, diff

I have two variables that return:

```
echo $var1
def abc ghi
```

```
echo $var2
abc def abc abc abc
```

I want the output to return as `ghi`

Comment: Doesn't look really hard. Have you tried anything on your own (at least something like `comm -3 <(echo "${var1// /$'\n'}" | sort -u) <(echo "${var2// /$'\n'}" | sort -u)`)?

Comment: @oguzismail I am new to this, tried couple of things but nothing working, this is working, thanks :)

Comment: Need to show some of the things you've tried.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per above comment, this worked for me
`comm -3 <(echo "${var1// /$'\n'}" | sort -u) <(echo "${var2// /$'\n'}" | sort -u)`